# Seg faulting when deleting linked list C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

As I'm traversing through a linked list it seg faults. I can't figure out why it's doing so. My assignment is to RECURSIVELY  (all functions) insert integers in order, make a function to check for an integer, print list, print list backwards, delete a node, and delete an entire list. I am on the last part and have been stuck for some time now. Thanks alot.

```
void deleteList(node* head)
{
    node* temp;

    if(head == NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");

    else
    {
        temp = head->next;
        free(head);
    }

    deleteList(head->next);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are first freeing the memory used by head and then passing a member of head as argument to "deleteList".

I think it should be first deleteList and then free:

```
if (head)
{
    deleteList(head->next);
    free(head);
}
```

Comment: Yeah... calling `head->next` will never work because head will either be NULL or will have been `free`d by that point.

Comment: I had that originally but it kept outputting garbage which is why I thought it was wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself... why are you storing the variable `temp`.  It doesn't look like you ever use it for anything.

I think you *meant* to use it, and you probably *should* use it.

Answer (score 1):

You've free'd head already, so when you're doing

```
deleteList(head->next);
```

you're accessing invalid memory, make use of your temp variable.

```
deleteList(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
    temp=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);
    deleteList(head);
```